# Dynamic Linq OR with int and string

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I have a very simple query that would look like this

```
select      *
from        job
where       jobId like '%23%'
or title    like '%23%'
```

I need to be able to replicate this using dynamic Linq

The closest i've come to is this, but it doesn't work

```
.Where("@0.Contains(jobId) or title.Contains(@0)", "23");
```

Has anyone got a solution to this, ideally I would like it to do a like on both int's and strings

**addendum based on comments**

The error is:

> An exception of type 'System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException' occurred in System.Linq.Dynamic.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: No applicable method 'Contains' exists in type 'String'

The `jobId` field is an `int`, while `title` is a `varchar`.

Comment: why you use `@0.Contains(jobId)`? in this case instead `@0` placed "23", so it look like `"23".Contains(jobld)`

Comment: Have you tried `.Where(x=>x.jobId.ToString().Contains("23") || title.Contains("23");`?

Comment: @Hintham used dynamic linq, so passed string instead expression

Comment: @Grundy You are correct, overlooked OP's requirement on using dynamic Linq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query is nearly right:

```
.Where("@0.Contains(jobId.ToString()) or title.Contains(@0)", "23")
```

Entity Framework (I hope you are using it) correctly changes `jobId.ToString()` to `CAST( [Extent1].[Id] AS nvarchar(max))`... It then uses a `CHARINDEX` instead of a `LIKE`, but this isn't a problem.

The query I get, with Entity Framework 6.1.3 on SQL Server is:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[jobId] AS [jobId], 
    [Extent1].[title] AS [title]
    FROM [dbo].[job] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (( CAST(CHARINDEX( CAST( [Extent1].[jobId] AS nvarchar(max)), N'23') AS int)) > 0) OR ([Extent1].[title] LIKE N'%23%')
```

Comment: My example was typed, I am passing a string as the paramater.

Comment: An exception of type 'System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException' occurred in System.Linq.Dynamic.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No applicable method 'Contains' exists in type 'String'

Comment: actual code is filterQuery = filterQuery.Where(where, filter); where = "@0.Contains(jobId) or title.Contains(@0)" and filter = "118"

Comment: No jobId is int and title is varchar, thus my title "Dynamic Linq OR with int and string"

Comment: There is no difference between "23" and int id = 23; id.ToString();

Comment: @DaleFraser If you are using Entity Framework, it should work. Untested on LINQ-to-SQL

Comment: @Tonci It was an example showing that if it had as a parameter an `int`, he could simply transform it to a `string`